# Can receive pointerDragged but not pointerPressed in a container

Tags: events, event-handling, swipe, codenameone

I have a UI in Codenameone where a container contains another container which contains some widgets.  On the bottom level container I'm able to receive pointerDragged events but not pointerPressed.  These (pointerPressed) seem to be consumed by the widgets on the top of the hierarchy, but not move down to the bottom container.

How can I fix this?

I'd like to do this to detect left-right swipes on the bottom container.  Is there perhaps a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Only focusable components receive the events directly in Codename One otherwise we would have to deliver events to multiple components which might inhibit performance.

The best way to do this is to use an existing component, e.g. `Tabs` supports swiping and hiding the tabs so you can just use that.

Making the `Container` focusable is probably not as desireable (although possible) since it might make interaction with the components within difficult.

You can use a pointer listener on the parent form as the `Tabs` component does internally. This should always work since the form gets all the events: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/

Comment: If the determining factor is if the component is focusable or not, why is there a different behaviour with pointerDragged and pointerPressed events?

Comment: The main reason for this is historic but generally when you press/release you do it in a single place (e.g. button click etc.) but when you drag you travel thru components. There are quite a few complex behaviors related to this that I can go into but generally drag is best implemented on the form or thru its listeners.